# Blocking Port 22 From Unknown IPs Security Measure

Tags: security, ssh, firewall, port

A server I'm working on has blocked all unknown addresses from accessing port 22 (via a firewall). An IP address has to be added to the firewall first via a control panel (or command line) before it can access port 22.

Is that a really good security measure? Are there ways that port 22 can still be hacked/penetrated given this measure? It's a really inconvenient measure (my IP changes almost on daily basis and I will have to update it). I still have access to that control panel to be able to add my IP, is that a weak point?

How effective/secure is this measure?

Comment: Having you're IP address change daily suggests this is a home environment which is off topic for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you have listening on port 22. Assuming it is just SSH, then this would be a way to keep the system quite secure. However, having port 22 open to all and just allowing authentication with SSH keypairs would also be very secure and a better trade-off.

Comment: +1 to @peter. Instead of blocking from unknown ip's to secure, instead disable password authetication completely and use ssh keys (PKI) .